# How to create a data grid with data store sub-array values in Ext 4?

Tags: arrays, json, extjs, multidimensional-array, extjs4

I have a multidimensional array as follows (PHP outputs to valid JSON), and have linked it via JSON data store to Ext. This is an excerpted version of the array:

```
    $data = array(
        "user"=>array(
            "details"=>array(
                "first_name"=>"John",
                "last_name"=>"Doe",
                "birthday"=>"03/21/1982"
            ),
            "campaigns"=>array(
                array(
                    "id"=>"19283",
                    "name"=>"Great Campaign One",
                    "status"=>3
                ),
                array(
                    "id"=>"59433",
                    "name"=>"Great Campaign Two",
                    "status"=>1
                )
            ),
            "notifications"=>array(
                array(
                    "id"=>"32143",
                    "subject"=>"This is a message for you",
                    "summary"=>"You need to do this and this...",
                    "read"=>0,
                    "status"=>3
                ),
                array(
                    "id"=>"54324",
                    "subject"=>"New Message too",
                    "summary"=>"More info for a great typer...",
                    "read"=>1,
                    "status"=>5
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Since I'd like to minimize server calls, I would like to call this record once and then access the sub-arrays (details, notifications, campaigns, etc) for separate data grids throughout my app. Do I need a separate store for each sub-array? or can I just use one store and access these directly in my Grids and Tpls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest different stores. In Ext 4, a store can be configured with a Model, which makes more sense in the context of something like "Notification" rather than entire "User" in your case. The reason is that putting all of the "User" data in one monolithic model will cause a lot of overhead code, because Ext Reader objects work natively against flat data sets. If you made each instance of a Model as monolithic as a user in your case, then you would need to add extra code to the read code of your Store's Reader.

Also, if each section of "User" is being used for a separate grid, then you definitely need different stores, because Ext grids are wired via single stores. And the grid will literally display the data in the store, where each row in the grid corresponds to a Model instance in the Store.

See [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store), [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model), and [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) for more details.